# Jquery countdown plugin disable onExpiry callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, countdown, jquery-callback

So I'm using keith wood countdown plugin.

```
$('#shortly').countdown({until: shortly,  
onExpiry: liftOff});
```

works as expected.

The thing is I need to disable the onExpiry when the user click on some button.
I mean to break the countdown and not to execute the callback method, in the example above not to fire liftoff method.

AnyIdea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, he's got pretty good documentation on his site:

http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html

```
$(selector).countdown('destroy')
```

or

```
$(selector).countdown('pause')
```

both seem like good places to start.

Comment: John wants to disable liftOff and not the countdown so please correct your answer

Comment: My answer provides the solution he is asking for.  Quoting directly from the question:  `I mean to break the countdown **and** not to execute the callback method`

Comment: Sorry If I wasn't clear enough, But actualy I want to break the countdown and to disable the liftoff invoke - which is exactly what Akousmata suggeted. that is why I accpeted this Answer.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of liftoff you can use a string variable and make it null on the click of button .

You may also read the documentation [here](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html) .

Here is the code which you can use

```
var dateObj = new Date(2012, 8 - 1, 8);
$(selector).countdown({ 
    until: dateObj}); 
$("#button").click(function(){
dateObj = null;});
```